# Can't embed XML in FlashDevelop

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flashdevelop, mxmlc

I am trying to embed some xml into my application but I get the following error

```
Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1090: XML parser failure: element is malformed.
```

Here is my code.

```
package 
{
    import com.objects.EngineApi;
    import com.objects.Rectangles;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author Anthony Gordon
     */


    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        [Embed(source = "com/files/level1.xml", mimeType = "application/octet-stream")]
        private var theClass:Class;


        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            var xmlObj:Object = new theClass();
            trace(xmlObj);
            var xml:XML = new XML(xmlObj) as XML;
        }

    }

}
```

xml code

```
< STAGE>
    < OBJECTS>
        < BLOCK X="2" Y="23" WIDTH="36" HEIGHT="4" />
        < SPAWN X="6" Y="22" />
        < BLOCK X="12" Y="21" WIDTH="4" HEIGHT="2" />
        < TUTORIAL X="18" Y="16" TEXT="..." />
        < TUTORIAL X="28" Y="22" TEXT="..." />
        < BLOCK X="36" Y="2" WIDTH="2" HEIGHT="16" />
        < JUMPTHRU X="32" Y="9" WIDTH="4" />
        < BLOCK X="27" Y="9" WIDTH="5" HEIGHT="2" />
        < COIN X="28" Y="7" />
        < COIN X="30" Y="7" />
        < COIN X="32" Y="7" />
        < COIN X="34" Y="7" />
        < BLOCK X="17" Y="8" WIDTH="5" HEIGHT="2" />
        < BLOCK X="2" Y="9" WIDTH="10" HEIGHT="2" />
        < CHEST X="19" Y="7" COINS="5" />
        < DOOR X="5" Y="8" />
        < BLOCK X="37" Y="20" WIDTH="2" HEIGHT="3" />
        < BLOCK X="1" Y="5" WIDTH="3" HEIGHT="4" />
        < BIRD_GOLD X="2" Y="4" COINS="3" TIME="5" />
    </ OBJECTS>
</ STAGE>
```

Comment: What does your XML look like?

Comment: 'XML parser failure' indicates that the error is in your xml file.
try opening it in firefox to see what the errors are.

Comment: I updated the code above. do I need a prolog ??

Comment: well it definitely was something in the xml. I tried another one and it worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is a runtime error, meaning the actual embed is working but the xml-parser croaks when reading it. This can mean many things, either that the markup is wrong to begin with, you're reading it wrong or that the actual embed breaks the xml somehow.

My bet is that this is where your problem is:

```
var xmlObj:Object = new theClass();
trace(xmlObj);
var xml:XML = new XML(xmlObj) as XML;
```

This will likely trace as [Object object] or something like that, which is the same string Flash will try to parse as XML.

I can't test this right now, byt try setting the mimetype of the embed to "text/xml" and doing like this instead:

```
var xml:XML = new theClass;
```